# iptables forward port to a different host

Tags: proxy, sftp, squid

I have a squid proxy which I want to forward sftp traffic to.

I set the `sftp_proxy` env var, however, since the port is non-standard, traffic is going through the default route, and not through the proxy server.

I want to set an IPtables rule that every outgoing connection to port 2323 would be forwarded to a different host (squid) on port 3128, and squid will in turn forward the traffic to the sftp host.

Is it something that can be configured?

Comment: yes, that's something that can be done. However, Squid is a caching HTTP proxy. Can't do anything sensible with sftp. What's the idea here? How are you planning to route something that's not HTTP through squid?

Comment: @MarcusMüller we define squid as a NAT server, it's not configured as transparent.

Comment: oh! But then, I don't understand; could you explain how squid can be used as a NAT server? NAT is something that is typically done by your network stack, not by a HTTP proxy daemon, that's why I'm very confused.

Comment: we use squid only for masquerading. on the first hand, we want to reduce AWS NAT costs, on the second hand, there are some endpoints that should not go through the proxy like 169.254.169.254 (ec2 metadata) and such.

Comment: OK; I really didn't know squid could even do that, but why use squid? The linux kernel does the same, at lower overhead. (I feel like if you're saving actual money on your AWS bill, then you've got a lot of traffic and you probably have a lot of clue about networking that I don't have, or at least I don't see in our discussion, sorry if that's the case; so, I'm really curious why you're using squid as NAT device, even if it means you need more compute resources than if you'd let Linux do that job.)

Comment: (..compute resources which you pay for, in the end)